# unique_ptr or shared_ptr for dependency injected classes with unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Is unique_ptr or shared_ptr more appropriate to use in a class that uses dependency injection and has unit tests for objects that are not shared with other instances.

Example:

```
class IFoo {
public:
    virtual void DoFoo()=0;
};

class RealFoo : public IFoo {
public:
    virtual void DoFoo() { /* ... */ }
};

class FakeFoo : public IFoo {
public:
    virtual void DoFoo() { DoFooCalled = true; }

    bool DoFooCalled;
};

class Bar {
public:
    explicit Bar(std::unique_ptr<IFoo> foo) : m_foo(std::move(foo)) { }

    void DoBar() {
        m_foo->DoFoo();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IFoo> m_foo;
};

class BarTest : public TestRunner {
public:
    void DoBarCallsDoFoo() {
        FakeFoo* rawFakeFoo = new FakeFoo(true);
        std::unique_ptr<FakeFoo> fakeFooPtr(rawFakeFoo);

        Bar bar(std::move(fakeFooPtr));

        bar.DoBar();

        Assert(rawFakeFoo->DoFooCalled);
     }
};
```

I have a minor debate going on with a co-worker on my team about this. I think that if Bar object is the only user of the Foo object in production, then unique_ptr is the correct pointer type. He argues that because we have to do that goofiness with storing a ref to the raw pointer in the test case that this is really shared semantics and a shared_ptr is the right pointer.

Which pointer type is right in this case?

Comment: You should really think of the new smart pointers in terms of *ownership*, and not as a ordinary pointers. Can a resource be owned by only a single entity at a time, or by multiple entities? When you know that you have the answer to your question. And when you have your answer, you design the unit tests around that.

Comment: That was my general thinking. In this case, without considering the unit test, the Bar object is the only owner of the IFoo object for the entire duration of the IFoo object's lifespan. Which is why I was arguing for the unique_ptr. However, with the unit test, we now want shared access to the IFoo object so that we can use it to sense that the Bar object is acting correctly. Hence it could now be considered shared and I have to deliberately circumvent the usage of a unique_ptr so that the test works.

Comment: Yes, but that sounds like a terrible idea, especially given that you have a work-around for the test.

Comment: Instead of doing that I would suggest you make two test-cases: One that actually tests the `IFoo` child-classes, and one that tests `Bar` without "knowledge" of the contained data in `Bar`. Alternatively do as you do now using the raw pointer.

Comment: You need  a `std::shared_ptr` when you can not control the order in-which objects that hold the reference will be destroyed. Hence you do not know which one must clean up the memory. Otherwise use a `std::unique_ptr`. If you want others to be able to point to the `IFoo` object in addition to the `std::unique_ptr` and those others will not outlive it, then use a raw pointer for them. They don't need a smart pointer because they will never be responsible for deleting it. Its all about ownership.

Comment: Re your comment: *"However, with the unit test, we now want shared access to the IFoo object so that we can use it to sense that the Bar object is acting correctly."* - I would distinguish between *shared access* and *shared ownership*. The only things that should be using smart pointers are things that are responsible for deleting the object (owners). Shared *access* should be through raw pointers imho when those *accessing* will never be expected to delete it..

Comment: Thanks everybody for the reasoned responses. I would accept the responses from @Galik if I could in this format. In general is sounds as if people are in agreement that a unique_ptr is more approriate in this context. And, to respond to JoachimPileborg's comments, I totally agree that the IFoo implementations also need their own tests. However, in the case where we're testing the functionailty of a void method on Bar, we have to hack into the "contained data" of Bar as it's the only way we have of sensing what's happening in that method. But, overall I agree.